# Delete on cascade not working on virtual machine

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, mariadb

I have a virtual machine in a server to which I uploaded my laravel project folder.

So in my localhost when I delete a "project" it deletes all "tasks" attached to that project, but this doesn't work on the vm, it just gives an error when you refresh the page

`Trying to get property of non-object`

On my localhost I use xampp.

Delete function on ProjectController:

```
public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        $project->delete();
        return redirect('/projects')->with('delete','');
    }
```

Project model:

```
public function tasks (){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task','proj_id');
    }
```

Task model:

```
public function project(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project','proj_id');
    }
```

I don't know what could be useful so just ask if you need any information.

Comment: may you add your piece of code what you have tried?

Comment: Please could you add the code that you are trying to run?

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR My problem here is not about the code itself. Everything is working fine on my local machine, relations are correctly formed and migrations are correct too

Comment: I added something @GeorgeHanson

Comment: Can you paste the full error that you see please?

Comment: ```Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/test5/resources/views/projects/index.blade.php)```

Comment: The issue then is in your blade template. Can you show the blade template please?

Comment: The issue is that in that view, it is trying to display something that I deleted, because ```onDelete('cascade')``` doesn't do what it's mean to do. That is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in **Project model** to remove related task before remove project:

```
protected static function boot ()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting (function ($project) {
        $project->tasks()->delete();
    });
}
```